# How to make neon lightning effect in unity 3d

Tags: unity, lightmap

How can i Create Neon Lighting effect in unity 3d ,[image]

[image]

[image]

so i have 2d scene and i want the rect to glow like neon

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the neon light effect in two different ways, depending on your lighting. If in your game you use static baking with lightmaps you could use an "emissive shader",  if you want to use realtime lighting with realtime shadows, you can use an emissive shader or an unlit one, and with pointlights or a spotlight. If you dont want to do everything by yourself there is also this [package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29160)

Comment: so there is no way to do with scripts and shaders

Comment: Yes, you can use shaders. Otherwise you could use post processing effects like Unity's post processing stack.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to perform a glow, particularly in 2D, is to make a blurred copy of your image and then blend it with the original image. You can use either a normal blend with a 50/50 mix between the original image and the blurred image, or you can use an additive blend. It can be helpful to threshold the original image before blurring it if you want only the brightest parts to glow. You can also give it a color cast before the glow if you want the glow to be a particular color.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm answering my question.

0. copy the following shader and create a new Shader ;

   ```
    Shader "Glow" {
        Properties {
            _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
            _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
            _Glow ("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
        }
        SubShader {
            Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            LOD 100
            Cull Off
            ZWrite On
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            Pass {
                CGPROGRAM
                    #pragma vertex vert
                    #pragma fragment frag

                    sampler2D _MainTex;
                    half4 _MainTex_ST;
                    fixed4 _Color;
                    half _Glow;

                    struct vertIn {
                        float4 pos : POSITION;
                        half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                    };

                    struct v2f {
                        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                        half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                    };

                    v2f vert (vertIn v) {
                        v2f o;
                        o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.pos);
                        o.tex = v.tex * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
                        return o;
                    }

                    fixed4 frag (v2f f) : SV_Target {
                        fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, f.tex);
                        col *= _Color;
                        col *= _Glow;
                        return col;
                    }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
   ```
1. create new material now select that shader from shader dropdown;
2. apply on your object;
3. import post-processing from asset store;
4. create new post-processing profile in project;
5. now select camera type post-pro and you get that script drag and drop your profile in it;
6. select bloom in profile and bam you are all done.

Comment: You should paste an image of the result.